# Enable autostart permission programmatically in devices where needed

Tags: android

I am using the background services and it does not run on some devices as I have to enable the autostart permission for the app. I want to enable the autostart permission automatically where it needs. I am using this code but it redirects me on the window where the autostart permission is.
Note :-- What I want , Not to redirect the user on the settings screen.

Here is my code for xiaomi

```
if (manufacturer.equalsIgnoreCase(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER)) {
//this will open auto start screen where user can enable permission for your app
Intent intent1 = new Intent();
intent1.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
startActivity(intent1);
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: You can try Work Manager if you like, but there is no way to do it programmatically

Comment: @AshutoshSagar Can you please explain how can i do that with work manager. If there no way that how can whatsapp receive the notifications?Because In Mi phones I have to enable the autostart permission so that services can run in background.

Comment: I don't think you can.  The system is designed to ask the user to grant permission whenever the app requests it. What you want to do goes against the system design and could be construed as attempting to implement a persistent malware that autostarts on system boot without letting the user know.

Comment: Famous apps like WhatsApp gets the allowance by default from Mi. I've also faced the same problem, but unable to get through it. You'll able lead to that setting screen at most.